# WP Plugin qTranslate bad post titles in Google News

Tags: qtranslate, google-news

I am the admin of the website: `www.hansa-online.de` and I started using `qTranslate X` just a few days ago.
Everything works fine, except the display of the post titles in google news. The title contains the language tags and also is build out of the 2 different language versions of the title. (Title in google news looks like this: [:de]Rickmers verkauft Trust-Manager[:en]Rickmers sells all trustee)

I have to find a quick solution for this problem because the news site is pretty big and if I can't fix the problem by the end of the day I have to stop using the `plugin`. Since everything else works fine I hope anyone can help me fix this issue.

Thanks
Lenni

Comment: It should not be. The problem in your theme. Either in the snippet that you use for google news. Or how do you use the plugin.

Comment: I have not changed any blog title settings of the qTranslate Plugin. Also I have noticed, the title is beeing displayes correct when both language fields have the exact identical / same input (all in the same language) Additionally I also use the YOAST Seo Plugin, maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Try this:
1. enable plugin qtranslatex
2. in chrome press F12 for developer console, click on "Element" tab
3. CTR + F for enable search in console, and try found [:en] tag. If you founded - past some code in you answer